# Timestamp issue - inconsistent behavior - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

In Postgres I have a function which accepts a `timestamp` parameter. 
I have a table which also has a `timestamp` column.

In the function code I do this. I take the input parameter and insert it 
into the table's timestamp column.

But now it turns out that my timestamp parameter
contains values like `2019-02-13 09:47:22:788125` 
while in the table I get just `2019-02-13 09:47:22:788000`.

So it seems that I lose precision (I lose these `.000125`) by just inserting into 
the table, even though both type of parameter and type of column are defined as 
simply `timestamp`. How come?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timestamp` values take a precision argument (see the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-datetime.html)).

So, although the values are both timestamps, they are not both necessarily of the same precision.

Comment: Thanks. So I thought... but then it means the `default precision for function parameters` is different than the `default precision for table columns`. Isn't this confusing and inconsistent behavior?! I've been on this doc page. Where are these two defaults stated there?

Comment: Never mind, I figured out that the column type is actually `timestamp(3)`. This explains it all. The parameter of the function is just timestamp which I guess means `timestamp(6)` (largest precision).